# Video, that lets user control the camera angle

Tags: html, video, html5-canvas, html5-video

The scenario: A guy walks along a route, through the crowd at a pool party.

The camera setup, is a customised rig with an array of GoPro's covering 360 degrees of rotation.

The end result needs to be a video that'll let the user

- click & drag the video to change his viewpoint on the video. So for eg, he can turn the angle to behind him, and will see where the guy has walked from. Or he can look sideways as he walks. (Likely some up/down movement too)
- pause playback
- zoom in/out

So for eg, you spot a hot girl in the crowd. You'd pause, zoom in and then play the video watching her as the guy walks past her.

How could this be achieved with HTML5 (non-Flash) methods?

I don't even know what technologies would be required to achieve something like this, so I'm hoping that someone with a bit of experience in something similar could give me some pointers as to required

- coding languages
- server technologies
- bandwidth considerations
- etc

Thanks for your help!
(ps: this is a paid client job. so if you can do exactly this, lets talk about a quote?)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be attempting something quite state-of-the-art.

The way I'd experiment with is to stream a video to the client and display it using WebGL, which the client can then manipulate without latency.

http://riaconnection.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/testing-live-video-streaming-to-webgl-and-html5-video-tag/

One way might be to stream 6 feeds - top, bottom, left, right, back front. These would be pre-processed so when displayed as a cube viewed from the center of the cube, the perspectives are corrected.

If the client can zoom in and out, then that means you'll need higher resolution stream. Six of them would mean very large bandwidth. You'll have to decide on a trade-off between bandwidth, quality and latency. If the client zooms in and changes pan / tilt, you could trade off latency and get better quality and bandwidth, but at the cost of higher server resource requirements.

There are plenty of video processing libraries for PHP, which would probably be my choice of server, but I'm biased.

Comment: Ya as I'm researching, I'm seeing this is pretty much a first-of-its kind type thing.

What about the Google Streetview API... is that a technology that could be employed in some way/form? Granted it might not be video, but if the route that the camera follows could be automated/plotted, that could achieve a simliar effect?

Comment: Google's Street View would have the same problems in terms of perspective and the types of image manipulation required, but your biggest problem will be bandwidth, server capabilities and latency, which street view is completely immune to since it's not video. So it wouldn't really be of any use to you.

Comment: Thanks Jodes. I've communicated this to my client and I think they understand the limitations.

Appreciate your time!